# Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 netlify

Tags: netlify

If you are trying to deploy on Netlify and you come across this error "Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1" Fix the upstream dependency conflict, I gave the solution below

Answer (score 2):

The error is a peer dependency conflict relating to versions of react, which provides guidance on how you can attempt to resolve it:

```
11:06:39 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
11:06:39 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
11:06:39 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

To do this on Netlify, you can use the `NPM_FLAGS` environment variable.

```
key:NPM_FLAGS value:--legacy-peer-deps
```

[image: screen shot of environment variable]

Answer (score 0):

Just use this command inside the build command input before deploying:
`CI= npm run build`